# Swift - How to check which image is assigned to button

Tags: swift, image

I'm trying to check if an image is assigned to a button. So far I use this:

```
if MyButton.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Black")) {
    //do something here
}
```

But I get error message:

> Use of unresolved identifier"MyButton"

even though I set the label of the button to MyButton.

Comment: You are running `currentImage` as if it's a static function. Run it on your button instance instead.

Comment: Also this line `UIImage(named: "Black")` instantiates a new image every time you run it. It will never be equal. Store your image you use on the button beforehand.

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new to swift and I don't get what you mean could you please show me example? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you do not have `MyButton` defined in your code. You should create a variable of type `UIButton` in which you store the button (connect it with outlet in storyboard or initialize it with code). Setting a label to the button as you mentioned will not do anything.